# powershell add user permission to a folder in windows server

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl

So I've got the next path: `C:\folder1\folder2\fileName`. Looking in the security tab on the **C:\folder1** there is **Alice** username with **full permissions**. But going to the **C:\folder1\folder2\fileName** Alice isn't there yet. How can I insert with powershell v2 Alice member **recursively** in C:\folder1 so that all the files under root C:\folder1 will also have the same Alice username set with full permissions.

---

I've tried:

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\folder1
$permission = "domain\Alice","FullControl","Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl C:\folder1
```

But it doesn't seem to apply for the C:\folder1\folder1\fileName. Guess I'm trying to apply permissions for Alice, which doesn't exist yet in the last fileName item.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [FileSystemAccessRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation, the class has a property for inheritance.
You have to add the property to your `$permission`

```
$permission = "domain\Alice", 
"FullControl",  
[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit", 
[system.security.accesscontrol.PropagationFlags]"None",
"Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
```

Comment: Something's wrong... PS C:\> $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "4".
At line:1 char:25
+ $accessRule = New-Object <<<<  System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: fixed. adjust the propagation flag by yoursefl as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also recursively add the permissions by getting all child items with the `Get-ChildItems` cmdlet and piping them to the `Set-Acl` cmdlet like they have done in an examle in the documentation on microsoft site here: [Set-Acl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/Set-Acl?view). Look at "Example 3: Apply a security descriptor to multiple files" or read below (copied from the page):

> ```
> PS C:\> $NewAcl = Get-Acl File0.txt
> PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Include "*.txt" -Force | Set-Acl - AclObject $NewAcl
> ```
>
> These commands apply the security descriptors in the File0.txt file to all text files in the C:\Temp directory and all of its subdirectories.
>
> The first command gets the security descriptor of the File0.txt file in the current directory and uses the assignment operator (=) to store it in the $NewACL variable.
>
> The first command in the pipeline uses the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to get all of the text files in the C:\Temp directory. The Recurse parameter extends the command to all subdirectories of C:\temp. The Include parameter limits the files retrieved to those with the ".txt" file name extension. The Force parameter gets hidden files, which would otherwise be excluded. (You cannot use "c:\temp*.txt", because the `-Recurse` parameter works on directories, not on files.)
>
> The pipeline operator (|) sends the objects representing the retrieved files to the `Set-Acl` cmdlet, which applies the security descriptor in the AclObject parameter to all of the files in the pipeline.
>
> In practice, it is best to use the Whatif parameter with all Set-Acl commands that can affect more than one item. In this case, the second command in the pipeline would be "`Set-Acl -AclObject $NewAcl -WhatIf`". This command lists the files that would be affected by the command. After reviewing the result, you can run the command again without the `Whatif` parameter.

This is an example using ".txt" files but can be modified to apply to directories as well.